# Need to move the main panel of a flash website from left to right

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

The panel is in ActionScript 2.0. it's located on the left side of the screen and slides from left to right as well. I want it to the right side and slide from right to left.

here's the code:

```
//
// INITIAL SETTINGS
//
spacer = 20;
destX = -bg_mc._width+spacer;
originX = this._x;
import mx.transitions.Tween;
import mx.transitions.easing.*;
//
// OPENING TRANSITION
//
// You can use custom easing types such as: Back, Bounce, Elastic, Regular, Strong, None
var tweenMenu:Tween = new Tween(this, "_x", Strong.easeOut, destX, destX, 15, false);
openMenu = function () {
    trace('openMenu')
    tweenMenu.continueTo(0);
};
// Detect mouse position
onMouseMove = function () {
    if (this.hitTest(_root._xmouse+1, _root._ymouse, true)) {
        activated = true;
        if (this._x != 0) {
            tweenMenu.continueTo(0);
        }
    } else {
        if (this._x != destX && activated) {
            tweenMenu.continueTo(destX);
        }
    }
};
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code that you showed all you need to do is:

1. Change your initial menu location (it will be stored in `originX` later on);
2. Change your `destX` variable value to desired one (at right side of the screen). It could be direct value, not calculated one.

**UPD:**
After looking your sources in comment all became clear.
To do what you planned you should do these steps:

1. Change your initial menu location
2. Change code inside `nav_mc` to

   ```
   //
   // INITIAL SETTINGS
   //
   spacer = 20;
   destX = Stage.width-spacer; //closed menu coord depends on your stage size.
   originX = Stage.width-bg_mc._width; //closed menu too.

   import mx.transitions.Tween;
   import mx.transitions.easing.*;
   //
   // OPENING TRANSITION
   //
   // You can use custom easing types such as: Back, Bounce, Elastic, Regular, Strong, None
   var tweenMenu:Tween = new Tween(this, "_x", Strong.easeOut, destX, destX, 15, false);
   openMenu = function () {
       trace('openMenu')
       tweenMenu.continueTo(originX); //there was mistake. your menu always goes to 0, and originX was
       //never used in code
   };
   // Detect mouse position
   onMouseMove = function () {
       if (this.hitTest(_root._xmouse+1, _root._ymouse, true)) {
           activated = true;
           if (this._x != originX) { //same here
               tweenMenu.continueTo(originX); //same here
           }
       } else {
           if (this._x != destX && activated) {
               tweenMenu.continueTo(destX);
           }
       }
   };
   ```

Because you project seems to be responsive to stage size changed, you also need to add these lines inside your `alignObjects = function () {...}` to provide correct menu positioning after possible changes:

```
nav_mc.destX = Stage.width-nav_mc.spacer;
nav_mc.originX = Stage.width-nav_mc.bg_mc._width;

if (nav_mc._x==nav_mc.destX) {
    nav_mc.tweenMenu.continueTo(nav_mc.originX);
}else{
    nav_mc.tweenMenu.continueTo(nav_mc.destX);
}
```

Comment: believe me Aspiro if I knew how to do that I wouldn't have asked it here. I tried to make some changes in the given locations and the panel flew to the middle. here's the source. please take a look and see what's wrong. http://www.mediafire.com/download/e1gy21hpnvimiy9/index.rar

Comment: Updated my answer. Check it out.

Comment: OMG! Thank you sooooooooooooooooooo musch Aspiro. You're a superhero!